# Why is Firestore still producing error after composite index creation?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore collection called "users".
here are three DB-reads I'm interested in executing:

1:

```
const onNewestChange = (dispatch) => {
    firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .where('role', '==', 'a')
        .where('active', '==', true)
        .orderBy('createdAt')
        .limit(10)
        .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            const newestProfiles = querySnapshot.forEach((queryDocSnapshot) => {
                const profile = queryDocSnapshot.data();
                newestProfiles.push(profile);
            });
            dispatch({ type: types.LOAD_NEWEST, payload: newestProfiles });
        });
};
```

2:

```
const onMostPopularChange = (dispatch) => {
    firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .where('role', '==', 'a')
        .where('active', '==', true)
        .orderBy('lifetimeInbox')
        .limit(10)
        .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            const popularProfiles = querySnapshot.forEach((queryDocSnapshot) => {
                const profile = queryDocSnapshot.data();
                popularProfiles.push(profile);
            });
            dispatch({ type: types.LOAD_POPULAR, payload: popularProfiles });
        });
};
```

3:

```
const onMostActiveChange = (dispatch) => {
    firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .where('role', '==', 'a')
        .where('active', '==', true)
        .orderBy('lifetimeRead')
        .limit(10)
        .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            const activeProfiles = querySnapshot.forEach((queryDocSnapshot) => {
                const profile = queryDocSnapshot.data();
                activeProfiles.push(profile);
            });
            dispatch({ type: types.LOAD_ACTIVE, payload: activeProfiles });
        });
};
```

An example "user" document has the following fields:

- username
- legalName
- role
- active
- createdAt
- lifetimeInbox
- lifetimeRead

I've created the following composite index :

[image: firestore-composite-index-screenshot]

Also tried:

[image: fireestore-composite-index-screenshot-2]

My problem is the initial error I was trying to resolve still persists even after the composite index creation

> Error: Firestore: Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution. (firestore/failed-precondition)

What can be done to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

After limiting my effort to just `onNewestChange()`, and playing with different composite indices, I realized that everything in the `where()` and `orderBy()` parameters need to be included as well as the collection being queried. so in my case...

1. requires a composite index with fields

   - role (asc)
   - active (asc)
   - createdAt (asc)
2. requires composite index with fields

   - role (asc)
   - active (asc)
   - lifetimeInbox (asc)
3. requires composite index with fields

   - role (asc)
   - active (asc)
   - lifetimeRead (asc)

Now the error is gone.